# gitignore to only track 2 directories with it's contents

Tags: git

I want to setup my .gitignore file to only keep track of 2 directories along with all files inside of them (with some exceptions like vendor). We do a lot of development for cPanel hosts and find it difficult with all other cPanel directories in the user directory to also want to be added to the local repo.

We have 2 directories we want to track
public_html
synergy

And want to exclude:
synergy/vendor (composer)
synergy/logs/* (only the files within this directory, not the directory)
public_html/uploads/*

I have tried the following (got it from another stackoverflow question) but this seems to exclude all subdirectories.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!synergy
!synergy/
!synergy/*
!public_html
!public_html/
!public_html/*

# Further specific excludes:
synergy/vendor
synergy/vendor/*
synergy/logs/*
/public_html/uploads/
/public_html/uploads/*
```

Comment: As a workaround, you could create two repos for those two directories you want to track instead of one repo for the parent folder with all the other directories inside you don't want to track.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/**` to select all subdirectories

```
*
!.gitignore

!a
!b
!a/**
!b/**
```